# If generating function of $\{ a_n \}$ is known what is the generating function of $\{ n a_n \}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Generating function of $\{ a_n \}_{0 \leq n}$ is $$A(x) = \frac{1+2x}{1-2x}$$
then what is the generating function of ${n a_n}$ ?

It is what I tried so far,

$$A(x) = \frac{1+2x}{1-2x}$$
$$= (1+2x)(1-2x)^{-1}$$
$$= (1+2x)(\sum_i \binom{i+1-1}{i}(2x)^i)$$
$$= (1+2x)(1+2x+4x^2+8x^3+...)$$
$$= (\overbrace{1+2x+4x^2+8x^3+...}^{1} + \overbrace{2x+4x^2+16x^3+...}^{2x})$$
$$A(x) = 1+4x+8x^2+24x^3+...$$
So we can say $a_0=1, a_1=4,a_2=8,a_3=24$,...

My problem is:

First: what is the meaning of $\{na_n\}$?, I found every element of $a_n$ is it true to say that $$na_n = $$
$$0 a_0 = 0 \times 1 = 0$$
$$1a_1 = 1 \times 4 = 4$$
$$2a_2 = 2 \times 8 = 16$$
$$...$$
?

Second, how to calculate $\{na_n\}$ as a formula look like what $A(x)$ is?

Comment: Hint: take (symbolic) derivative of your generating function of $\{a_n\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: If the generating function of a sequence $\{a_n\}$ is $A(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, then its derivative is simply $A'(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}$, and so, $xA'(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}na_nx^{n}$.

Comment: Was my statement true when I said : is it true to say that $$na_n = $$
$$0 a_0 = 0 \times 1 = 0$$
$$1a_1 = 1 \times 4 = 4$$
$$2a_2 = 2 \times 8 = 16$$
$$...$$?

Comment: Yes, you did correctly compute the first few terms of the sequence $\{na_n\}$.